# Saying for "don't talk about things you don't understand"

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests

Is there a (relatively) common phrase, preferably using a metaphor, which means one should not talk about things one does not really understand?  I have the impression of some such phrase floating around in my memory, but all that I can think of is *Do not meddle in the affairs of wizards*, which is not the phrase I am looking for.

Comment: Things are going to get quiet real quick.

Answer (score 2):

I've always liked:

> Better to be thought a fool than to open your mouth and remove all doubt.

And:

> You are in *way* over your head. [Better keep your mouth shut or you'll drown.]

Answer (score 2):

A phrase I often use...

I'm [out of my depth!](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+out+of+depth)